# Software which will help simulate some of keystrokes?

Tags: keyboard, simulation, keystrokes

My title is define my question so I will give and example:

When I push 'alt + w' it will send keystrokes something like "write me".I mean that all this text will be written by keystrokes.

I tried clavier but I think it doesn't simulate keystrokes ,it paste that text .

I am waiting suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the [keyboard macro feature](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm) in autohotkey will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TypeItIn](http://www.wavget.com/typeitin.html), it is quite handy but however not free.

[image] [image]

> TypeItIn lets you create groups of buttons that will type any information you want into any application.
>
> You can use TypeItIn to complete forms on the web, or process forms at work.
>
> It's a great tool for applications where you frequently type the same thing like creating HTML code or writing standard letters or emails.
>   Another great use is for entering user names and passwords. You can also launch applications or web sites with the click of a button.
>
> TypeItIn can automatically type in the time or date, work with the clipboard, move & resize windows, and control Internet Explorer.
>   You can also Record your typing to automatically create buttons.